# Example about function continuous at 0 but not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I need an example for a function $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$ which is continuous and attains a global maximum at $0$, but not differentiable at $0$.

I have been thinking about it for 2 hours and still not get it yet, so I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The classic example of a function that is continuous but not differentiable is an absolute value function. Transform this function such that it attains its global max at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x)=-|x|?{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$